# R (R commander) - Sample

Tags: r, sample, random, r-commander

I'm struggling with sample function
How can I sample 50 samples from dataset variable?
In my dataset, there are 82 variables and I dunno how to sample from just one variable...;;
I just wanna sample(randomly, without replacement) 50 samples from a variable at R commander(or R)

plz help!

Comment: Try `sample(data$column, 50)` For example, run `sample(iris$Sepal.Length, 50)` Here `iris` is the data set and `Sepal.Length` is the column name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either the column index or the column name.  Here's an example that samples ten values from the first column of the `iris` data set.  Then the second line shows that sample being implemented three times.

```
sample(iris$Sepal.Length, 10L)   ## or sample(iris[[1]], 10)
# [1] 6.7 6.6 4.9 6.3 5.2 5.2 5.1 5.0 4.9 6.4
replicate(3L, sample(iris$Sepal.Length, 10L))
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
#  [1,]  5.1  5.6  5.6
#  [2,]  6.9  5.0  5.1
#  [3,]  4.4  6.9  6.5
#  [4,]  7.2  5.8  5.5
#  [5,]  5.7  7.7  6.7
#  [6,]  4.8  5.0  5.0
#  [7,]  5.0  6.2  5.8
#  [8,]  5.9  5.6  6.0
#  [9,]  4.9  4.9  6.1
# [10,]  5.6  6.1  7.2
```